# Saying "Hello" to family members?

Tags: word-choice, culture

On lang-8 I read a message from a Japanese speaker who said that 「今日は」isn't used among family/friends, but mainly for strangers.

To this end I need ask, what is a common way to say "Hello" to family/friends, or at least the Japanese equivalent if they have a different custom in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the site below a native Japanese student admits he doesn't greet his family or friends.
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1465002114

But that is not considered good manners. As an adult you are supposed to greet promptly and correctly.
A child may get away with it, but not an adult.

こんにちは is the proper way to greet people.
I don't think there is a good substitute for it.
Any possible substitute will be probably a slang or dialect, which by definition is used by a small group of people and may not be appropriate for certain situations.

If it is a close friend you could maybe say something like "元気?"
I had a co-worker who used to greet people with "おっす".

Comment: "You are REQUIRED to greet everyone" yup, sounds like Japan alright! :D

Comment: I didn't say you are "required". Nobody is going to arrest for failing to greet people, especially family and friends.
But that is not considered good manners, that is all.